# Need Help With NSTimer To Make Stopwatch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I want to create a timer that countdowns 60 seconds and updates a UILabel with the time left.

I have this so far, but how do I connect the int to the time left?

```
-(IBAction)startTimer
{
    NSTimer *myTimer;
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
}

- (void)countDown
{
    counterInt--;
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counterInt];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSTimer is not the way to go for applications that require precise time measurement.  The time interval you specify is only a goal and the NSTimer is not guaranteed to fire at precisely that time.  It tries to hit the goal you specify but particularly if the processor is handling a lot, NSTimer accuracy deteriorates.

To accurately measure time you need to use NSDate to record the time when you begin and then go ahead and run the NSTimer the way you are but instead of assuming that an exact second has passed, have your function compare the current time with the start time and that will give you an accurate measurement.

Comment: This also facilitates pausing the timer if such is desired.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `timeInterval` as 60 seconds so it will be triggered every 60 seconds and not every 1 second for 60 seconds. So it should be,

```
myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(countDown:) 
                                          userInfo:nil 
                                           repeats:YES] retain];
```

Another thing is that you are not invalidating the alarm after your purpose is done. So check whether the `counterInt` value has reached zero and invalidate it. Since there is another benefit to it, **make `myTimer` an instance variable.**

```
- (void)countDown:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    counterInt--;
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counterInt];

    if ( counterInt <= 0 ) {
        [myTimer invalidate];
        [myTimer release];
        myTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Furthermore you are not handling the case where the stop watch has already started. That part should be handled in your interface action method,

```
-(IBAction)startTimer:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ( myTimer ) {
        /* Timer exists so handle that as appropriate */
        [myTimer invalidate];
        [myTimer release];
        myTimer = nil;

        [sender setTitle:@"Start" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain]; 
        counterInt = 60;

        [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have edited the answer to change the method to take an `NSTimer` instance as a parameter. You will have to update the method definition accordingly. Update the code too.

As such `counterInt` is something that you should declare as an instance variable.

Comment: `NSTimer` actions are required to take one argument, which is the timer. Combined with the fact that the run loop retains the timer, this means it's not always necessary to keep it in an ivar; you always have a reference to the timer when it fires. It is necessary if you might want to stop it in another method, or, as you pointed out, (for a long-running timer) to check whether it's already running.

Comment: Thanks Deepak,but I'm getting error saying `counterInt` has not been declared.  What should I declare it as?

Comment: @Josh I agree that the documentation says that and I will change my answer to reflect that but this does work without complaints. Strangely though.

Comment: @Jon Added an edit to my answer. You will have to update the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks deepak, what kind of iVar though? Just Int *counterInt?

Comment: No just `int counterInt;` would do.

Comment: Jon I think you are not declaring your counterInt as an instance variable.  That means that you declare it in the .h header file.  That way it remains even after the function is complete.  Variables that are declared in the function are only valid for that run through the function and are eliminated on completion.

Comment: Ya thanks I got that now, unfortunately nothing is hapeping when I clcik the start button.  And I double checked the connections in IB.

Comment: @Deepak: Now that you mention that, I seem to recall seeing that. Hmm...it's probably building an `NSInvocation` internally; maybe that has something to do with it. /shrug

Comment: Ok it wasn't working because in your 3rd method you have 60, instead of 1 for time internal.  Do you know how to make it so that when you chick the start button while timer is running, it turns it off?

Comment: @Jon Errors of copy paste. :) I have added some code to the third code snippet that will turn it off.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, also remove `[myTimer release];` because we made it an iVar remember.  And also, si there an easy way to change the button's text from start to stop while timer is on?

Comment: No don't remove the release. Memory management won't balance. We are retaining it when we are creating it so we must release it too.

Comment: @Jon updated the answer. But I have to ask, have you referred to any books on iOS?

Comment: It was crashing with dealloc error when the release code was there.  I already release it in dealloc method

Comment: Didn't get you. But we are `nil`ing it out after releasing it so it shouldn't crash in dealloc.

Comment: Aren't I supposed to release all instance variables in `dealloc` method though? Isn't that memory management 101?

Comment: No you should. And I didn't say otherwise. I said since you are making the instance variable `nil` so it shouldn't crash as you would be sending the `release` message to `nil`. However you should add `[myTimer invalidate];` before the `release` call in `dealloc`.

Comment: Continuing OT: In fact, it seems that `NSTimer` will take a selector that has any number of parameters without complaint; there's just no way to pass an actual argument other than the timer itself when it fires.

Comment: For this line `[sender setTitle:@"Start" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];`, I am getting error method not found, return type defaults to id.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=1522